# Rails render partial control as container

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I know in many language when rendering control, there is option to make the control as container of data

for example in asp.net mvc

```
<asp:reader....>
<item template>
<div class="bla"> Some html string </div>
</item template>
</asp:reader>
```

also in angularjs i know the posibilty to config controller as container.

I want to know if in rails i can do some staff like this
Something like

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/partial/page-description'>
<my html string>
<% end %>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a partial as a layout for other content. So your layout partial, `_my_div.html.erb` might be:

```
<div class="my_div">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Then you can use it in another view like this:

```
<%= render layout: 'my_div' do %>
  <div>My content</div>
<% end %>
```

Which as you'd expect gives you the output:

```
<div class="my_div">
  <div>My content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `:layout` option with a block is what you are looking for.

```
<%= render :layout => 'layouts/partial/page-description' do %>
 <p>Hello World</p>
<% end %>
```

In your view you can use `<%= yield %>` to add the content to your template at a certain place.

Answer (score 0):

here is my working code, thanks

```
<%= render :layout => 'layouts/partial/page-description', :locals => {:title => 'General Report'} do %>

        <br><br>
        <strong style="color:#f16321;font-weight:bold"> bound to ensue </strong> 
        <% end %>
```